# Destructor issue with delete[]

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind, new-operator, delete-operator

For a program I'm writing, I wrote a simple array wrapper class (the idea is that it's supposed to be fixed-size. I know I could just use std::vectors)
And I have an issue when deleting the Array. 
Those are my constructors:

```
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(size_t size): m_data(new T[size]), m_size(size)
{}
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(const std::vector<T> &vec): m_size(vec.size())
{
    std::allocator<T> a;
    m_data = a.allocate(m_size);
    for(int i = 0; i<m_size; i++)
    {
        new (m_data+i) T(vec[i]);
    }
}
```

And this is my destructor:

```
template <class T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    delete[] m_data;
}
```

I used valgrind to try to figure out what's going on, but it didn't help.

```
==20840== Invalid read of size 8
==20840==    at 0x10ABB8: sapph_dijkstra::Array<sapph_dijkstra::Node>::~Array() (in /home/sapphie/dijkstra/test)
==20840==    by 0x1091CF: sapph_dijkstra::MinHeap::~MinHeap() (minheap.h:40)
==20840==    by 0x109021: main (test.c:20)
==20840==  Address 0x5b21318 is 8 bytes before a block of size 400 alloc'd
==20840==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20840==    by 0x109F99: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<sapph_dijkstra::Node>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:111)
==20840==    by 0x10AA36: sapph_dijkstra::Array<sapph_dijkstra::Node>::Array(std::vector<sapph_dijkstra::Node, std::allocator<sapph_dijkstra::Node> > const&) (in /home/sapphie/dijkstra/test)
==20840==    by 0x10A232: sapph_dijkstra::MinHeap::MinHeap(std::vector<sapph_dijkstra::Node, std::allocator<sapph_dijkstra::Node> > const&) (in /home/sapphie/dijkstra/test)
==20840==    by 0x108FD1: main (test.c:20)
==22059== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==22059==    at 0x4C3173B: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22059==    by 0x10ABA4: sapph_dijkstra::Array<sapph_dijkstra::Node>::~Array() (in /home/sapphie/dijkstra/test)
==22059==    by 0x1091CF: sapph_dijkstra::MinHeap::~MinHeap() (minheap.h:40)
==22059==    by 0x109021: main (test.c:20)
```

(I've cut some identical error messages) 
In the prints I've done, I've figured out that the address I allocated is at `0x5b21320`, so indeed the address shown by valgrind is 8 bytes before that.
But I don't understand why. I don't seem to access that. 
Is there something trivial I'm missing?
I realise that this is probably an overly complicated solution for a problem where I could just use a standard vector, and I'm probably gonna change to that. But I'm mostly curious now.

Comment: What does `a.allocate(m_size);` do?

Comment: It's to allocate the memory for the array before initialising anything. That way, if T does not have a default constructor, but only a copy constructor, this code still works (in my case I have a class where a default constructor wouldn't make sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete using `delete[]` if the memory wasn't initialized using `new[]`. This is one situation (of very, very, **very** few situations) where it's correct to directly call an object's destructor:

```
template <class T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
        m_data[i].~T();
    }
    allocator.deallocate(m_data);
}
```

There's a few other changes you should probably make:

- The allocator object should be a member of the `Array` object, not a local object in its constructor. While most allocators are not stateful, some are, and having to create a local copy of the allocator only within the constructor means that your allocator is going to lose its state.
- You should make an executive decision as to whether you want the objects to be destroyed in the same order that `delete[]` destroys objects. In your situation, you need to specify that yourself, by altering the order of the for-loop in the destructor.

This is what that would look like:

```
template <class T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
        m_data[m_size - i - 1].~T();
    }
    allocator.deallocate(m_data);
}
```

- I would also make sure you avoid using `int` for anything involving sizes of this array. There's an argument to be made to prefer `int64_t` over `size_t` (though that would break from how the STL behaves, and is a decision that would need to be made carefully), but you definitely don't want to cap yourself to using a signed 32-bit number or smaller (which `int` is on most environments).

#### Regarding the choice not to use `delete`:

`delete` expects the pointer passed to it to be its own discretely allocated object. Objects created using placement-`new` are not allocated this way. Consider the following:

```
struct point {
    int32_t x, y;
};

int main() {
    char memory[1024];
    size_t size = 128;
    point * arr = reinterpret_cast<point*>(memory);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        new(memory + i) point();
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i].x = 5;
        arr[i].y = 10;
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //undefined behavior, we're deleting objects that weren't allocated on the heap!
        delete (arr + (size - i - 1));
    }
}
```

In this example, there's no dynamic allocation of memory at all; all memory used is allocated on the stack. If we used `delete` in this situation, we'd be deleting pointers to memory on the stack, and any number of (undefined) things could happen, most likely including crashing our program. Calling the destructor allows the object to clean up its component objects without needing to perform the (in this case, unnecessary) deallocation of memory.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    //Correct behavior, doesn't delete stack memory
    arr[size - i - 1].~point();
}
```

Even in the situation where this memory *was* allocated on the heap, we'd still be deleting pointers that weren't expressly allocated by the code. That's forbidden by the language, and it's easy to see why: a single deallocation of the original memory erases the whole chunk of allocated memory, there's no need to deallocate the individual chunks.

```
struct point {
    int32_t x, y;
};

int main() {
    char * memory = new char[1024];
    size_t size = 128;
    point * arr = reinterpret_cast<point*>(memory);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        new(memory + i) point();
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i].x = 5;
        arr[i].y = 10;
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //Still UB: only the first object is a discrete allocation, the rest are part of
        //that original allocation. This attempts to deallocate the same chunk of memory 128 times
        //delete (arr + (size - i - 1));

        //This is correct
        arr[size - i - 1].~point();
    }
    //We do need to deallocate the original memory allocated, but we only do this once.
    delete[] memory;
}
```

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. I wonder though; how come you don't use `delete` instead of the destructor, since it was allocated with `operator new`? I understand now why I can't use `delete[]`, but what's the advantage of the destructor method?

Comment: @sapphie I added a section regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `new` and `delete[]` which is undefined behavior.  `std::allocator::allocate` uses `operator new`, not `operator new[]`, so you have to call `delete` on it.

Since you are mixing how you allocate storage you need to keep track of which way you allocated it so you can deallocate it correctly.

You can avoid all of this though by just having a `std::vector` as the data member of the class.  Then your constructors become

```
template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(size_t size): m_data(size) {}

template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(const std::vector<T> &vec): m_data(vec) {}
```

And you get the benefit of not having to store the size member as the vector does that for you.